# Ruby on Rails migrate error after add these 3 gems in my gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

After adding these 3 gems:

```
gem 'carrierwave',             '0.10.0'
gem 'mini_magick',             '3.8.0'
gem 'fog',                     '1.26.0'
```

And then I did bundle exec rake db:migrate, I got:
[image: error log]

Comment: I have typed bundle install before migrate. Sorry about not mention it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your Gemfile: `gem 'net-ssh'` and run bundle install after that. Looks like the particular version of fog you are using is missing the dependency. This is a known bug that has already been fixed in successive versions of the gem.